# How to implement a Switching Time Test Circuit for IRF520 MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I am trying to recreate the circuit shown below:
The data supplied from the Electrical Characteristics Table of the Infineon IRF520 MOSFET data sheet shows the following selection:

VDD = 50V 
ID = 5.7A 
RG = 22Ω
 RD = 8.6Ω, See Figure

I am using a signal generator which produces a pulse width of 1us and 10V peak.

However, I am not familiar with the concept of Duty Factor and that it has to be <= 0.1% can anyone explain that concept. What needs to be configured at the signal generator to achieve this duty factor?

I have looked at [www.wikipedia.org](http://www.wikipedia.org) and found the following explanation:
“The duty factor for periodic signal expresses the same notion, but is usually scaled to a maximum of one rather than 100%”

But according to the schematic, the Duty Factor is a percentage of 0.1%. Which is a contradiction.

Your kind response is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: *concept of Duty Factor* I suggest that you quickly calculate how much **power** is dissipated in the MOSFET while it is switched on and ID = 5.7 A. That would heat up your MOSFET and possibly destroy it if you're not careful. So instead of keeping it on 100% of the time, we swith it on only for a short moment, like 0.1% of the time. 0.1% means 1 in 1000. So 1ms every second or 100 us every 100 ms.

Comment: Or 1us every 1 ms (or longer)

Comment: Thank you for your contributions. I did heat up the MOSFET though it was before your clarification. Now I know what is meant in the data sheet.